# Display tbar above tabs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a sencha fiddle:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/4gr

The TBar button is visible in all tabs, because it is a tbar of the tab panel.

I think you all agree that "TBar Button", as long as it is at the very same position where it is now, should only have an effect on the active tab, right?

So, how on earth can I get the tbar to display above the tabs, where a user would intuitively guess correctly that it has effect on all tabs?

Comment: I hope there is a better option than this one, however, one option could be to nest inside another panel.  [Check out this fiddle for example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/4h6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using **tbar**, you can use the **tools** option to configure a button for the whole tab panel.

```
    var panel = Ext.create("Ext.tab.Panel", {
        layout: 'fit',
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        autoRender: true,
        tools: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'TBar Button'
        }],
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'A'
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'B'
        }]
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to order dockedItems by using `weight`:

```
var panel = Ext.create("Ext.tab.Panel", {
    layout: 'fit',
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    autoRender: true,
    dockedItems: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'TBar Button'
            }],
            weight: -2
        }
    ],
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'A'
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'B'
    }]
});
```

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1sph